# Unable to create a null constant value of type

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to create new objects from my Entity Framework linq query, however I am getting an error which I will show below along with my code.

```
    var dashboards = await Db.Dashboards
             .Select(dashboard => new DashboardViewModel
             {
                 DashboardID = dashboard.DashboardID,
                 DashName = dashboard.DashName,
                 Shared = dashboard.Shared,
                 GlobalRefreshCycle = dashboard.GlobalRefreshCycle,
                 widgets = null
             }).ToListAsync();
```

and here is my error:

> Unable to create a null constant value of type. Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context

Comment: Remove `widgets = null`. It's probably unnecessary anyway.

Comment: @haim770 More precisely, if `widgets` is a reference type (class) and is not set by the constructor then it will be `null` by default.

Comment: what is type of widgets? is it reference type?